# PHP code doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to create a user system but there is a section of the code that won't execute. I am using ajax to pass the values to PHP but this one block just doesn't execute and I have no idea why.

**PHP**

```
<?
/* New Follower */
include_once("php/check_user_log.php");
include_once("php/db_conx.php");
if(isset($_POST["follower"])){
echo "success_1";
if ($_POST["follower"] == "yes"){
    echo "success_2";
    $follower_id = $log_id;
    $following_id = $_GET["u"];
    echo "success_3";

    $curr_followers = $followers;
    $new_followers = $curr_followers.",".$follower_id;
    echo "success_4";

    $follower_update = "UPDATE users SET followers='$new_followers' WHERE username=$following_id";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $follower_update);
    echo "success_5";

    $follower_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$log_id' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
    $follower_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $follower_sql);
    echo "success_6";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($follower_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $follower_following = $row["following"];
    }
    echo "success_7";

    $curr_following = $follower_following;
    $new_following = $curr_following.",".$following_id;
    echo "success_8";

    $following_update = "UPDATE users SET following='$new_following' WHERE id=$log_id";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $following_update);

    echo "success_9";
} else {
    echo "fail_1";
    exit();
}
}
/* End New Follower */
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
function newFollower(){
            var new_follower = "yes";
            if(new_follower == ""){
                $(".logo").html("new_follower not set");
            } else {
                var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "profile.php");
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                        if (ajax.responseText == "success_1"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_1");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_2"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_2");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_3"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_3");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_4"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_4");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_5"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_5");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_6"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_6");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_7"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_7");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_8"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_8");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "success_9"){
                            $(".logo").html("success_9");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "fail_1"){
                            $(".logo").html("fail_1");
                        } else if (ajax.responseText == "fail_2"){
                            $(".logo").html("fail_2");
                        } else {
                            $(".logo").html("unknown error");
                        }
                    }
                }
                ajax.send("follower="+new_follower);
            }
        }
```

If there is anything else that you would like to know, just ask as I'm not completely sure what information you'll need.

Comment: Is there any error in the error_log file ?

Comment: No. The error log is empty

Comment: Your PHP code checks `isset($_POST["follow"])` and using `$_POST["new_follower"]` while your AJAX action appears to be posting `follower=`

Comment: `follower`!=`follow` OR `follower`!=`new_follower`-> `ajax.send("follower="+new_follower);` vs `if(isset($_POST["follow"]))`&&`if ($_POST["new_follower"] == "yes")`

Comment: I just changed it to `isset($POST["follower"])` but it's still not executing

Comment: Also, you will have issues with `$_GET["u"]` as you are posting to `profile.php` -> `ajaxObj("POST", "profile.php")` with no `?u=`

Comment: Did you change both `if(isset($_POST["follow"]))` && `if($_POST["new_follower"] == "yes")` to `$_POST["follower"]`?

Comment: Yeah. I've changed both to `$_POST["follower"]`

Comment: And $_GET["u"] is already set

Comment: How is `$_GET["u"]` already set when you are doing an ajax post to `ajaxObj("POST", "profile.php")`? The `?u=` on your current page will not magically forward to your ajax call to `profile.php`.

Comment: The page they are viewing is their profile page and it has already been set through the URL

Comment: But you have to pass that value to the ajax. Ajax is like opening a new tab or window. If you don't add it to the url in `ajaxObj("POST", "profile.php")` then it will not transfer over.

Comment: Even if all the code is on one page that has $u set through the url?

Comment: Yes. your current page might be `profile.php?u=1`, but your ajax code is opening up `profile.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sean. Your comment about ajax opening the page profile.php not the current page was the issue.